# Different texture space in the same mesh?

Tags: texturing

I'm using 2 different textures on the same mesh. The first looks right with a texture space of 10x10x10 on the mesh, while the second needs a texture space of 100x100x100 to look right. Can I assign different texture spaces to different parts of the same mesh?

I don't want to modify the material because it is used on other objects as well and I would prefer not to separate the mesh into two meshes unless there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, the texture space is an attribute of the texture, not the material, so if you have two materials with different textures, each texture will have its own texture space; if you have two materials that use the same texture, both materials will have the same texture space. So, you can have two different texture spaces, but they need to be assigned to different materials, although the two materials themselves can be identical (except for the material name), one for each texture.

Comment: I checked this again, this is what I found: the scale of a texture can be adjusted individually. But the texture space (which you can set under properties/object data/texture space) will change the texture space for the whole mesh. I guess I wanted to use different texture space rather than scale because with texture space I can work with real units (cm).

Comment: So if you know of a texture space (not scale) adjustment that affects individual textures and can be set separately for different textures, please let me know where to find it.

Comment: I'll have a better answer later.  I'm on the road at the moment and can't confirm my answer before I post it. But I suspect that what I was referring to you would call "scale".

Answer (score 0):

Using the Blender Render engine you can alter the Mapping properties of the texture to use UV coordinates, and then select from the list of however many UV maps you have created.

[image: uv map alpha or dos]

Under the Cycles rendering engine you have similar capabilities, but since everything is based on nodes it looks like this instead:

[image: cycles]

Even if you want to use something other than UV maps, Blender Render has access to per-texture size and offset values in the Mapping panel.  Cycles would just include math nodes between the non-UV texture coordinate source and the vector input of the texture node.